# Vertical table header in vuetify

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to display a table with a vertical header instead of the traditional horizontal header. Since the table has to be under another table that is using Vuetify, I want to make the vertical table using the same layout using Vuetify as well.

In plain html/css I know that you can optain this using TH as rows:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">A</th>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">C</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, Vuetify doesn't allow that much of modification of its framework and I can't find any other way using their documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/

Is there any other way to make a vertical table with Vuetify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify body inside v-data-table with slots.

```html
 <v-data-table
            :items="desserts">
            <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="header in headers">
                    <td>
                        {{ header.text }}
                    </td>
                    <td v-for="item in items">
                        {{ item[header.value] }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
```